# Open source JavaScript chart library as alternative to Spotfire for browser-based data visualization

Tags: open-source, library, javascript, data-visualization, charts

Tibco Spotfire's professional client and web player are great tools, but very expensive.  I'd like to find an open-source, browser-based (ideally JavaScript) alternative for creating feature rich charts with minimal configuration.  The ideal solution would have the following characteristics:

- Support for bar charts, scatter plots, box plots, and heat maps.
- Custom tooltips.
- Zooming/panning.
- Brush selection.
- Ability to pass data from chart to other JavaScript functions.

I cannot count the number D3-based libraries I have looked at, none of which seem to support all of the above features.  Do any open source alternatives to Spotfire exist?

Comment: Here is a comparison of JS charting frameworks - it is somewhat limited in feature comparisons, but you may find helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_JavaScript_charting_frameworks